# Is possible to obtain a list of debian packages that doesn't have a gui / run in X?

Tags: debian, apt

I'm interested into creating a script able to get my own iso of debian for offline working purposes, however I have no the need of any gui utility that are generally for desktop usage.

For the purpouse i want to create my jigdo template but i have to feed him with a list of packages i need, so i have to include all the base os packages and this is the topic of the question: a list of all command line tools and services.

Examples of stuff that should be included:
bind9, unbound, nginx, apache2, all php5 packages, python, ruby..

Excluded:
libreoffice...

Kept the same in: that progs that have both a cli version and a gui (if possible taking the cli only)

Is there any source i can use for this? A website to parse or running apt-cache with some switches?

Not asking you the full script, just some hints where to start for get a list of this packages..

Comment: You could try selecting using debtags. Selecting `interface::text-mode` would be a start.

Comment: @FaheemMitha this in apt-cache ? thanks man, probably after got all the info I need I will write an answer here for the sake of the community by myself with the full code :)

Comment: No, you use the `debtags` command to search the package tag database. Try something like: `debtags search 'interface::commandline'`

Comment: @FaheemMitha good, this weekend I will make some tests, some hints where i can find a list of the basic packages instead for a debian installation ? or just copy the ones from the netinst or cd1 ?

Comment: https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#list-image-contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A start would be using the package tags information, for example the `interface::commandline` tag. The command

```
debtags search 'interface::commandline'
```

selects all packages matching `interface::commandline`.